# Can JavaScript variables be used for dynamic MDX headings, in Docusaurus?

Tags: jsx, docusaurus, mdxjs

### Question

Suppose I have a string `variable`, e.g. `const variable="foo";`

Is there a way to create dynamic headings in Docusaurus, by using MD syntax. For example something like:

```
# Heading {variable}
```

### Problem

For a variable: `const variable="foo";`

Tried:

`## Heading {variable}`

Expected to get a heading like:

**Heading foo**

Got instead:

**Heading {variable}**

### Description

There is a use case that I need to create a set of headings based on some JS strings. Trying out the above does not work because it appears that everything after a `#` is used in the produced heading **literally** - including the curly braces and the variable name - thus, the value of the `str` variable is not used.

I've managed to make this work by going the React-way and using the `<Heading/>` component, defined in `@theme/Heading`. But there are certain caveats to these:

- Level of heading(indentation) has to be explicitly defined for each `<Heading>` component.
- Slugified heading `id` must be manually computed
- Headings rendered this way feel appear to be styled smaller than the ones that would be rendered using MD. For example `<Heading as={'h2'} id={'a-heading'}>A heading</Heading>` will be smaller from the equivalent `## A heading`